# Using jq with a large JSON file

Tags: json

I have an extremely large JSON file that I am working with, on my Linux box. When I jq the file I get an output in this format, which is perfect:

{
“ID:” 12345
“Name:” joe
“Address:” 123 first street
“Email:” joe@example.com

My goal is to be able to grep for a particular field but get all related fields to return. So if I did a grep for “123 first street” I would also get the ID , name, and email that was with that group of data.

Thus far, I have gotten here:

jq . Myfile.json | grep “123 first street”

Can anyone help with me with getting this query right? I would like to stay with this JSON format and stay in the Linux box.

jq . Myfile.json | grep “123 first street”

Answer (score 0):

This should return all JSON objects with "field".

```
jq '.[] | select(has("field"))'
```